# Cross-platform method to detect whether /dev/tty is available & functional

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, tty

I have a bash script from which I want to access /dev/tty, but only when it's available.

When it's not available (in my case: when running my script in GitHub Actions) then when I try to access it I get `/dev/tty: No such device or address`, and I'm trying to detect that in advance to avoid the error and provide fallback behaviour instead.

To do so I need a bash test that can detect cleanly this case, and which will work reliably across platforms (i.e. not using the `tty` command, which has issues [on Mac](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/5760)).

I'm currently using `[[ -e "/dev/tty" ]]` which doesn't work - it appears to return true even on GitHub Actions, where it seems that /dev/tty exists but accessing it will fail. What should I use instead?

Comment: Would [this page of the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html) be useful?

Comment: No idea why, but `$-` contains "hBH" in my bash, not `i`, so that example doesn't work.

Comment: For what purpose does the bash script want to access /dev/tty ?

Comment: @Philippe to launch $EDITOR connected to the TTY, from inside a pipeline of other commands (so no direct access to stdin/stdout). When /dev/tty is available that works great, and when it's not I can provide an OK fallback, but I need to be able to detect that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After testing lots of promising but not quite perfect suggestions (see the other answers), I think I've found my own solution that does exactly fit my needs:

```sh
if sh -c ": >/dev/tty" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
    # /dev/tty is available and usable
else
    # /dev/tty is not available
fi
```

To explain:

`: >/dev/tty` does nothing (using the `:` bash built-in) and outputs the nothing to /dev/tty, thereby checking that it exists & it's writable, but not actually producing any visible output. If this succeeds, we're good.

If we do that at the top level without a /dev/tty, bash itself produces a noisy error in our output, complaining about /dev/tty being unusable. This can't be redirected and silenced because it comes from bash itself, not the `:` command.

Wrapping that with `sh -c "..."  >/dev/null 2>/dev/null` runs the test in a bash subshell, with stdout/stderr removed, and so silences all errors & warnings while still returning the overall exit code.

Suggestions for further improvements welcome. For reference, I'm testing this with `setsid <command>`, which seems to be a good simulation of the TTY-less environment I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Good idea, you can just do `bash -c ': >/dev/tty' ...`

Comment: That's even better! Thanks @Philippe, I've updated the answer

Comment: Indeed, this seems a simple and portable solution :-)

Comment: Is there a reason for using `sh -c ': > /dev/tty'` instead of `{ : > /dev/tty; } > /dev/null 2>&1` ?

Comment: @Fravadona Yes, braces do not work there. On my system, `setsid sh -c '(printf a; { : >/dev/tty; } 2>/dev/null; printf b); printf c'` prints `ac` instead of the expected `abc` (`setsid` detaches the `sh -c ...` from any terminal that the caller may use, so that `/dev/tty` is not useable by the shell.). Using parentheses instead of braces makes it work as expected: `setsid sh -c '(printf a; ( : >/dev/tty; ) 2>/dev/null; printf b); printf c'` does print `abc`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adapting [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/753459/480533) from [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/146745/480533) (entitled *How can I check in bash if a shell is running in interactive mode?*, which is close to your question albeit not an exact duplicate) could be a solution for your use case.

So, could you try writing either:

- `[ -t 0 ] && [ -t 1 ] && echo your code`
- or `[ -t 0 ] && echo your code` ?

For completeness, here is one link documenting this POSIX flag `-t`, which is thus portable:

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

> `-t  file_descriptor`
> True if file descriptor number file_descriptor is open and is associated with a terminal.
> False if file_descriptor is not a valid file descriptor number, or if file descriptor number file_descriptor is not open, or if it is open but is not associated with a terminal.

Furthermore, if you use `bash` (not just a POSIX-compliant shell), you might want to combine this idea with the special `255` file descriptor number: `[ -t 255 ]`.

Source: On Unix&Linux-SE,

> That `255` file descriptor is an open handle to the controlling tty and is only used when `bash` is run in interactive mode.
> […]
>
> − [In Bash, what is file descriptor 255 for, can I use it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475396/297058) (by [**@mosvy**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/308316/mosvy))

Comment: In my case, stdin & stdout are pipes to other processes, so -t 0 & -t 1 are false, and this won't work. I still want to communicate with the controlling TTY when one is available though, by using /dev/tty directly. When /dev/tty is available this works fine! But not in completely TTY-less environments.

Comment: OK but do you think you could adapt my suggestion and "keep" the stdin available via another FD number, just for this test purpose?

Comment: How? Can you give an example? This script is run as part of a pipeline, so it never has any access to the TTY via stdin or any FD, so I can't "keep" it.

Comment: For example, if you use `bash` (not just a POSIX shell), I've just seen in [this SE thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/475389/297058) that the special FD number 255 (to make available `/dev/tty` even if stdin/stdout have been redirected) might be a solution for you to test (namely, `[ -t 255 ]`…)

Comment: FD 255 is an option, that might work. It would be better to have an option to test /dev/tty itself though, without being dependent on bash internal implementation details. I'd really prefer to check the state of the tty device I want to use directly, rather than patch in another workaround.

Comment: @TimPerry yes, this definitely sounds like a workaround :'-) but which might work on Mac also, thanks to the availability of `bash`… (let us know if ever you can test this)

Comment: I tested this, and it works in some cases, but not all cases. When running `bash ./test.sh` in an interactive terminal for example `[ -t 255 ]` is incorrectly false.

Comment: Indeed, but this does not look wrong to me − the fact that `[ -t 255 ] && echo true` is false with `bash ./test.sh` → it would certainly print true with `bash -i ./test.sh`; but maybe this is not exactly the criterion you want to test.

Comment: Yes - that's not the right criterion. I'm only interested in whether /dev/tty is available (and it is by default when you run any bash script in an interactive terminal, with or without -i).

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach :

```
if  test "$(ps -p "$$" -o tty=)" = "?"; then
    echo "/dev/tty is not available."
else
    echo "/dev/tty is available."
fi
```

Comment: I've done some testing and this seems to work pretty well! I've upvoted but I'm going to use my own slightly simpler answer below that just uses printf & bash instead, just because I'm slightly worried that complex ps commands like this might work slightly differently on Mac and other weird environments (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300864/how-to-get-the-basic-linux-ps-functionality-in-mac for example).

Comment: So running via cron, I got a zero exit status with the output `??`. On my mac terminal I get `ttys004` as the output. So I think this test needs to be adjusted to check for any ? rather than a single question mark. Other than that, this was the only reliable way of detecting it.

Comment: Here is an updated variation `[[ "$(ps -p "$$" -o tty=)" != '?'* ]]`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of spawning a new shell process to test if `/dev/tty` can *really* be opened for writing (`test -w` lies, you know?), you can try to redirect stdout to /dev/tty from a subshell like so:

```
if (exec < /dev/tty) ; then
  # /dev/tty is available
else
  # no tty is available
fi
```

This is POSIX syntax and should work in any shell.

Comment: This still generates noisey error for me: `line 15: /dev/tty: Device not configured`

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the other answers mentioned in this thread (and as an alternative to the other idea involving `$-`, [which did not seem to work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69075612/cross-platform-method-to-detect-whether-dev-tty-is-available-functional/69076005#comment122084074_69075612)), what about this other idea mentioned in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html)?

```sh
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
    echo This shell is not interactive
else
    echo This shell is interactive
fi
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but this doesn't seem to work reliably unfortunately... In my testing, when running a saved script in bash (v5) then $PS1 is unset, even if it's set in the terminal itself & /dev/tty is working (also: this actually needs to be ${PS1+x} to handle the case where it's set but empty).